# Let install app from a user chosen store

Tags: android, maps, google-play

Im currently developping an app in China. I have a small problem, on the chinese phones Google Maps is initially not installed but i need it for the application. For the users its no problem to install it but i want them to have a choice which market to use.

```
public void someButtonClicked(View v) {

    if (!isGoogleMapsInstalled()){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
public boolean isGoogleMapsInstalled()
{
    try
    {
        ApplicationInfo info = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0 );
        return true;
    }
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this is what i have and actually it only opens the play store but i cannot decide which store to use.

As last sorry for my bad English.

Comment: "Other Store " Does that mean you want to install the app from some other store which hostes app like google play store ???


IF yes then simply replacing the URL "market://details?id=com.google.android.apps.maps" with "www.mystore.com/app" should work It will Open the browser for you from where you can first download and then install teh app...

According to me It will not happen perfectly like the Play sotre do

Comment: That's the correct Intent and it's up to OEMs (store app providers) to add "market:" Uri handler to their respective stores.

Comment: problem is China has many stores and i am sure it containts the play store. But im a dutch guy and i KNOW these are some of the shops but i have no idea what the website can tell me about how to call it :(

安卓市场 or 91助手 are both app stores containing google maps..